# Rgd: Copy Table from one connection to another

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have this table call

```
table1 that use $connection (that is tie to database DB1)
```

I have another table call

```
table2 that use $connection2 (that is tie to database DB2)
```

I wanna copy table1 record (1 of the row using where condition) into table2

I use something like

```
INSERT into table 1(column) select * from table 2 where ID='$record'
```

Problem is when I execute my **sqlsrv_query**

I can only choose **1 sql connection** to execute, how do I fix this issue such that I can **select statement using connection2** and **insert statement using connection1**. in 1 sqlsrv_query